# Problemas com mouse hover em css

Tags: css-hover, mouse

tudo bom? estou com o seguinte problema com mouse hover, comecei a ver algumas aulas de html e css e estou com um projeto pessoal, eu fiz um código simples apenas para estudar mouse hover porém ele não funciona corretamente, já tentei display: none/block, visibility: hidden, filter: opacity e nada o mouse hover não funciona, sendo que é de uma classe para outra.

Este é o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mapa"><a class="loja"></a></div>
<div class="descri">LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM 

IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM 

IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM 

IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </div>
</body>
</html>

<style type="text/css">


.mapa {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: green;
    float: left;
}

a.loja {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin-top: 29px;
    margin-left: 53px;
    transition: 1s;
}

a.loja:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: red;
}

a.loja:mouseover .descri{
    display: block;
}

.descri {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 21px;
    font-size: 10px;
    display: none;
}
```

Alguém por gentileza, pode me dizer onde estou errando?

Grato.

Comment: Boa tarde, não existe mouseover em css. Existe sim 'onmouseover' mas isto é um evento de HTML e é usado na tag. Normalmente é usado para chamar uma função de javascript.

Comment: No CSS o que existe é hover, mas sobre isso já está uma resposta em baixo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não existe *mouseover* no CSS.

Portanto, o bloco abaixo está errado.

```
a.loja:mouseover .descri{
    display: block;
}
```

Tente assim, troque *:mouseover* por *:hover*:

```
a.loja:hover .descri{
    display: block;
}
```

Além disso, você está colocando seu estilo em local errado, o correto mesmo seria em um arquivo externo, mas como você está utilizando no mesmo arquivo você tem que colocar seu tag de `style` dentro de `head`.

Código completo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .mapa {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background: green;
            float: left;
        }

        a.loja {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background: black;
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 100px;
            margin-top: 29px;
            margin-left: 53px;
            transition: 1s;
        }

        a.loja:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            background: red;
        }

        .loja:hover .descri {
            display: block;
        }

        .descri {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            float: left;
            background: black;
            color: white;
            text-align: justify;
            padding: 21px;
            font-size: 10px;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="mapa">
        <a class="loja"><div class="descri">
        LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM </div></a>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Opa, Boi meu caro, o bloco onde estava mouseover foi um teste que estava vendo na internet, estava usando o :hover mesmo, e mesmo usando :hover e colocando o estilo dentro do head, ainda não funcionou.

Comment: Eu fiz uma edição no código, agora irá funcionar, desculpe a demora!!!
Sua div `.descri` precisa estar dentro de `a.loja`.

Comment: Só para me esclarecer então, a estrutura que vai aparecer tem que estar dentro da classe que vai ser o :hover, correto?

Comment: Neste caso sim, existe várias formas de fazer um efeito hover, de maneiras diferentes, isso dependerá da criatividade de cada um.